# QNX and its preemptive scheduling

Tags: qnx

I am sorry if I mis-understand some notions.

QNX OS is described as a RTOS. My naive understanding for RTOS is that one task is promised to be executed by the OS on a relativly precise time.

BUT I also learn that the scheduling way of QNX is preemptive, which is to say task of lower priority can be interrupted by the higher one.

SO, my question is why do we still say QNX is RTOS and its behavior is deterministic?